# How to append string to file if it is not included in the file?

Tags: bash, text-processing, netstat

### Protagonists

- The Admin
- Pipes
- The Cron Daemon
- A bunch of text processing utilities
- netstat
- `>>` the Scribe

### Setting

The Cron Daemon is repeatedly performing the same job where he forces an innocent `netstat` to show the network status (`netstat -n`). Pipes then have to pick up the information and deliver it to bystanding text processing utilities (`| grep tcp | awk '{ print $5 }' | cut -d "." -f-4`). `>>` has to scribe the important results to a file. As his highness, The Admin, is a lazy and easily annoyed ruler, `>>` only wants to scribe new information to the file.

```
*/1 * * * * netstat -n | grep tcp | awk '{ print $5 }' | cut -d "." -f-4 >> /tmp/file
```

### Soliloquy by `>>`

```
To append, or not append, that is the question: 
Whether 'tis new information to bother The Admin with 
and earn an outrageous Fortune,
Or to take Arms against `netstat` and the others, 
And by opposing, ignore them? To die: to sleep;
```

*note by the publisher: For all those that had problems understanding Hamlet, like I did, the question is, how do I check if the string is already included in the file and if not, append it to the file?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are dealing with a very big file, you can use the `uniq` command to remove the duplicate lines from the file. This means you will also have the file sorted, I don't know if this is an advantage or disadvantage for you:

```
netstat -n | grep tcp | awk '{ print $5 }' | cut -d "." -f-4 >> /tmp/file && sort /tmp/file | uniq > /tmp/file.uniq
```

This will give you the sorted results without duplicates in `/tmp/file.uniq`

Comment: by the way, awesome way to form a question :-)

Comment: It works for me. I slightly modified it by using `sort`s capabilities to only return unique items and output the result to a file: `netstat -n | grep tcp | awk '{ print $5 }' | cut -d "." -f-4 >> /tmp/file && sort -u -o /tmp/file /tmp/file`

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Since you want to sort the content of the existing file along with the output of netstat command.

Comment: `netstat -n | grep tcp | awk '{ print $5 }' | cut ... | sort -u > /tmp/file`. Doh?

Answer (score 1):

```
What a piece of work is piping, how easy to reason about, 
how infinite in use cases, in bash and script, 
how elegant and admirable in action,
how like a vim in flexibility, 
how like a gnu!
```

Here is a slightly different take:

```
netstat -n | awk -F"[\t .]+" '/tcp/ {print $9"."$10"."$11"."$12}' | sort -nu | while read ip; do if ! grep -q $ip /tmp/file; then echo $ip >> /tmp/file; fi; done;
```

Explanation:

```
awk -F"[\t .]+" '/tcp/ {print $9"."$10"."$11"."$12}'
```

Awk splits the input string by tabs and ".". The input string is filtered (instead of using a separate grep invocation) by lines containing "tcp". Finally the resulting output fields are concatenated with dots and printed out.

```
sort -nu
```

Sorts the IPs numerically and creates a set of unique entries. This eliminates the need for the separate `uniq` command.

```
if ! grep -q $ip /tmp/file; then echo $ip >> /tmp/file; fi;
```

Greps for the ip in the file, if it doesn't find it, the ip gets appended.

Note: This solution does not remove old entries and clean up the file after each run - it merely appends - as your question implied.